# Does File Vault store unencrypted data even if encryption is enabled in File Vault?

Tags: filevault

I noticed that a new File Vault 2 Backup volume first is backed up to, than encypted (for a few hours).

So the first backup is unencrypted??? I already didn't like that about a new install of lion.

Comment: Could you perhaps rephrase this into a question rather than a statement! IMO just because you _can_ encrypt the backup device does not mean it is a good idea in all cases. If this is meant to allow you to recover your system in the event of catastrophic failure you are introducing a barrier to easily recovering it. Perhaps physical security of the backup device would be a sufficient safeguard. Certainly there will be cases where the drive must be encrypted.

Comment: Well, the first backup is eventually encrypted when the volume finishes encrypting, it's not sitting there unencrypted for all time.